# Command raised an exception: OpusNotLoaded:

Tags: python, discord.py

I just started programming a discord bot with discord.py and everything is perfect.
Except one thing: I can't let the bot play music.

Here is my code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def yt(ctx, url):

    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

My error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: 
Command raised an exception: 
OpusNotLoaded:
```

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`discord.opus.load_opus`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.opus.load_opus) to load the Opus library.

Comment: Should I import this?

Comment: Yes.  You should also make sure that `libopus` is installed on the computer the bot is running on.