# Heroku on Discord Bot youtube_dl and discord[voice] error

Tags: python, heroku, discord

Bot Code :

```
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "e!")

players = {}

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot çevrimiçi!")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def baglan(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def oynat(ctx, url):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start() 


client.run('')
```

Error :

```
packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'
```

The bot is normally running on my own PC but I am currently running on a `Heroku` server. The bot joins the channel but doesn't play the audio.

I couldn't figure out a way how to solve this problem
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114464/command-raised-an-exception-opusnotloaded/51114499#51114499).  You need to load the `libopus` shared library.

Comment: ~ $ python -m pip install opuslib
Requirement already satisfied: opuslib in ./.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: You need to load it in your bots code using the [`load_opus`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.opus.load_opus) function

Comment: I don't understand. can you tell me how?

Comment: [See this example bot](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/playlist.py#L5)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    discord.opus.load_opus('opus')
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/opus.py", line 124, in load_opus
    _lib = libopus_loader(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/opus.py", line 60, in libopus_loader
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(name)
OSError: opus: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: "or libopus.so on linux in the current directory" do you have a `libopus.so` file?  The argument to `load_opus` should be the path to that file.

Comment: Heroku isn’t a virtual server, it does not bear well with the opus library. It’s recommended by the discord developers community to *not* use heroku to host bots since the platform isn’t meant for bot hosting as its unstable (downtimes) and doesn’t support opus (without extended modifications).