# How to play sound with a music discord bot on heroku

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, bots, discord.js, opus

I'm creating a Discord Music Bot in discord.js, I already installed ffmpeg, and everything seems to work normally, but when I execute play command, bot joins a channel, send a message, but doesn't play anything, I've already checked console and it doesn't log anything.
I know it's not a problem with code since it works perfectly locally, the problem is when I try to use heroku, I thought it could be a opusscript problem but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find code relevant here, since it works perfectly in my localhost, but when I start to host it at Heroku, nothing happens.
Here you have it, maybe there's an error, but as I said I think the problem is with opusscript or node-opus.
[Here are my Heroku buildpacks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtrOp.png)

And this is my code:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

let voiceChn = message.member.voiceChannel;

if(!voiceChn) return message.channel.send('¡Join a voice channel first!.'); 

if(!args) return message.channel.send('Add a youtube URL to play it.');

voiceChn.join()
    .then(connection => {
        const url = ytdl(args.join(' '), { filter : 'audioonly' });

        const dispatcher = connection.playStream(url);

        message.delete();

        message.channel.send('Now playing : '+ args);

    }).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth I am seeing a very similar issue. My bot should join the channel, play a sound clip from a S3 bucket (which is made public), and then leave.
Here's my code:

```
async function executePlaySoundCommand(message, filePath) {
  try {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
    const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
    console.log(`filePath: ${filePath}`);
    const file = `${process.env.S3_URL}/${filePath}`;
    console.log(`file: ${file}`);
    const dispatcher = await connection.playArbitraryInput(file);
    console.log('Playback finished');
    dispatcher.on('end', () => {
      voiceChannel.leave();
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Locally the bot will join the channel, play the sound and then leave as expected. However in heroku, the bot will join the channel, then immediately leave. 
Below are the sanitized logs from heroku:

```
Executing <command-name> command
filePath: <audio-file>.mp3
file: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<s3-bucket-name>/<audio-file>.mp3
Playback finished
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with my code(?), looking into [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#Description) protocols to see if I have missed something.

Comment: Just found this on another stack overflow post. `Heroku isn’t a virtual server, it does not bear well with the opus library. It’s recommended by the discord developers community to not use heroku to host bots since the platform isn’t meant for bot hosting as its unstable (downtimes) and doesn’t support opus (without extended modifications).` From here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372170/heroku-on-discord-bot-youtube-dl-and-discordvoice-error)